# how can we run multiple applications with different domain & port numbers in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I Have two applications running on my server with domains

```
 x.abc.com
 admin.x.abc.com

x.abc.com is running on port 80
admin.x.abc.com is running on port 8080
```

I can able to access x.abc.com from browser, but when I try admin.x.abc.com, it is sending requests to x.abc.com only.

What is the proper way to configure two different web applications with different domain & port on single machine. Listed below my virtualhost files for x.abc.com & admin.x.abc.com respectively

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.x.abc.com
    ServerAlias x.abc.com
    RailsEnv test
    DocumentRoot /home/cp/cp/public
   <Directory /home/cp/cp/public/>
   </Directory>
   LogLevel warn
   ErrorLog /home/cp/cp/log/error.log
   CustomLog /home/cp/cp/access.log combined
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.x.abc.com
   RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.admin.x.abc.com
    ServerAlias admin.x.abc.com
    RailsEnv test
    DocumentRoot /home/cp/cp_admin/public
   <Directory /home/cp/cp_admin/public/>
   </Directory>
   LogLevel warn
   ErrorLog /home/cp/cp_admin/log/error.log
   CustomLog /home/cp/cp_admin/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The  `RewriteRule` in your first `VirtualHost` entry looks unintended, as it redirects the request to your server to the clients machine. You might want to review that.

Comment: You didn't mention it, but did you add the `Listen 8000` near the `Listen 80`?

Comment: I have added Listen 80 & Listen 8080 already

Answer (score 1):

You can add mutliple `VirtualHost` directives for a single port. Apache will process them according to the names, i.e. `ServerName`and `ServerAlias`. Note that Apache defaults to the *first* `VirtualHost` configured, if no match is found. The following configuration should work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.admin.x.abc.com
    ServerAlias admin.x.abc.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.x.abc.com
    ServerAlias x.abc.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: No it was not working, I have tried already

Comment: Have you ensured that *both* hosts listen on port 80?

Comment: The order of these two virtual hosts should perhaps be reversed to prevent `ServerAlias x.abc.com` matching `admin.x.abc.com`, as the [ServerAlias directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) suggests would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your config seems to be good. Try the following:

1. Are you using domains or IP? If it does not find the virtual host your are referring to, **it will serve the first virtual host**. In this case, www.x.abc.com. This is regardless of port.
2. Try to add the **Listen 8080** directive. You should have both Listen 80 and Listen 8080.

Comment: I have added Listen 80 & Listen 8080 already

Comment: Starting httpd: [Thu Apr 21 02:26:53 2016] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what may be happening is that (1) all the traffic is being handled on port 80, and then (2) the `ServerAlias x.abc.com` is matching (and being used for) `admin.x.abc.com`. Note, from the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) regarding matching:

> Name-based virtual hosts for the best-matching set of `<virtualhost>`s are processed in the order they appear in the configuration. The first matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` is used, with no different precedence for wildcards (nor for ServerName vs. ServerAlias).

Answer (score -1):

It is resolved after adding the below line in httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHosts *:80
```

Comment: First, I assume that you mean `NameVirtualHost` as there is no `NameVirtualHosts` directive. Second, although the timing you describe may be correct, i.e. "it resolved AFTER adding the NameVirtualHost," this was probably not the CAUSE of the resolution. To be sure, the `NameVirtualHost` directive is deprecated in Apache 2.4. and, as noted in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost), "This directive currently has no effect."

Comment: @Colt It got fixed after adding this and FYI my Apache version is 2.2. Do you have  any other solutions for this?

Comment: Well, that changes about everything. Inaccurately tagging your question not only makes it very difficult for people to help you, but makes the question/answer confusing for people finding this thread in the future. I edited the tag from Apache 2.4 to Apache 2.2. The `NameVirtualHost` is required for Apache 2.2.